# Compiling PyGAMMA Mac Lion: g++ cant find standard C++ header files (string / iostream...)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, osx-lion

im trying to compile PyGAMMA according to these instructions http://scion.duhs.duke.edu/vespa/gamma/wiki/PyGammaBuildingLibrary:

My setup:
XCode: 4.5.1 + CommandLineTools
MacOSX Lion

I get the following output:

```
~/gamma/platforms/OSX $ make pysgdist

Include directory: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
Library directory: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Checking for python include and lib directories

Good. The Python Includes Directory Exists. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
Good. The Python Library Directory Exists. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -I../../src  -D_USING_LAPACK_ -O3 -arch x86_64 ../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc -o ../../mac-darwin/Gutils.pso
In file included from ../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:33:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:33:50: error: string: No such file or directory
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:34:60: error: iostream: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:35,
from ../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:33:
../../src/GamGen.h:163:19: error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:37:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:38:18: error: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:33:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:52: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:52: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:54: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:54: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:56: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:56: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:58: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:58: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:59: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:59: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:60: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:60: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:77: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:77: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:78: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:78: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:79: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.h:79: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:40: error: ‘std::string’ has not been declared
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:41: error: ‘std::cout’ has not been declared
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:42: error: ‘std::cin’ has not been declared
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:43: error: ‘std::endl’ has not been declared
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:61: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:61: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:63: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:64: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:64: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:64: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:64: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:68: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:68: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:68: error: redefinition of ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:61: error: ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:70: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:70: error: ‘atof’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:71: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:71: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:71: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:71: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:75: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:75: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:75: error: redefinition of ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:61: error: ‘void query_parameter(int, char**, int, int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:77: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:77: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:78: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:78: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:78: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:78: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:82: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:82: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:85: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:85: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:89: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:89: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:90: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:91: error: expected `;' before ‘ss’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:91: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:92: error: ‘ss’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:93: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:98: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:98: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:98: error: redefinition of ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:82: error: ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:101: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:101: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:105: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:105: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:106: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:107: error: expected `;' before ‘ss’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:107: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:108: error: ‘ss’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:109: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:109: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:114: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:114: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:114: error: redefinition of ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:82: error: ‘bool ask_set(int, char**, int, int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:117: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:117: error: ‘atof’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:121: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:121: error: ‘Q’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:122: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:123: error: expected `;' before ‘ss’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:123: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:124: error: ‘ss’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:125: error: ‘V’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:125: error: ‘atof’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:143: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:143: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:154: error: expected `;' before ‘s’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:154: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:155: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:155: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:155: error: ‘noret’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:155: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:158: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:158: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:158: error: redefinition of ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:143: error: ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:160: error: expected `;' before ‘msg’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:160: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:161: error: ‘eidx’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:163: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:163: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:164: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:165: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:166: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:167: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:168: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:169: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:170: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:171: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:172: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:173: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:174: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:175: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:176: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:177: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:178: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:179: error: ‘noret’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:179: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:181: error: ‘hdr’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:181: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:181: error: ‘noret’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: At global scope:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:184: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:184: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘string’ with no type
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:184: error: redefinition of ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:143: error: ‘void GAMMAerror(int)’ previously defined here
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:186: error: expected `;' before ‘msg’
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:186: warning: statement has no effect
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:187: error: ‘eidx’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:189: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:189: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:190: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:191: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:192: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:193: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:194: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:195: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:195: error: ‘pname’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:196: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:197: error: ‘string’ cannot be used as a function
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:199: error: ‘hdr’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:199: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:199: error: ‘pname’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:199: error: ‘noret’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc: In function ‘volatile void GAMMAfatal()’:
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:204: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:204: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
../../src/Basics/Gutils.cc:205: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [../../mac-darwin/Gutils.pso] Error 1
```

It seems that the standard C++ includes are not automatically included.
Does somebody have a hunch on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it..

1) Tell gcc about the usual C++ standard header. Therefore change:
SRCDIRINCL = -I$(SRCDIR) 
to
SRCDIRINCL = -I$(SRCDIR) -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/

2) Tell gcc about the usual osx framework path and include the Accelerate framework. Therefore change:
LAPACK_LIBS =
to
LAPACK_LIBS = -F/System/Library/Frameworks/ -framework Accelerate

Should work fine now.